# Get list of properties in LINQ projection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following LINQ expression:

```
var query = entities
  .Select(e => new MyObject() 
  {
    Property1 = e.Item1,
    Property2 = e.Item2
  });
```

MyObject might have also Property3, Property4 defined. I need to realize which properties are part of LINQ projection via expression visitor.

So I call something like:

```
var listOfProperties = query.GetSelectedPropertyNames();
```

and the content of listOfProperties will be string array which contains `Property1, Property2` or something by which I can check:

```
var isPropertyInProjection = query.HasPropertyInProjection(nameof(MyObject.Property3));
```

and the result will be false.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this completely statically? I assume that `MyObject` is a specific type.

Comment: You could use a dictionary : dict = new Dictionary<string,object>}{"Property1",e.Item1},{"Property2",e.Item2}}

Comment: @Codor Yes, you can basically access the properties that have been bound.

Comment: What LINQ provider are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do that using an `ExpressionVisitor`. Just create a new class and override the visiting methods. If you know that the projection was done using member bindings, you can simply override the method `VisitMemberBinding` and add the bound member to a list that you store as an instance variable. Then all you need to do is to make that instance variable public.

```
class ProjectionAnalyzer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private HashSet<MemberInfo> boundMembers = new HashSet<MemberInfo>();

    protected override MemberBinding VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
    {
        boundMembers.Add(node.Member);
        return base.VisitMemberBinding(node);
    }

    public IEnumerable<MemberInfo> BoundMembers => boundMembers;
}
```

Then, use this class as follows:

```
var analyzer = new ProjectionAnalyzer();
analyzer.Visit(selectorPredicate);
var boundMembers = analyzer.BoundMembers;
```

How you obtain the selector predicate depends on your LINQ provider.

Comment: I was playing around with something like that, and it seems you need to override `VisitMember` instead of `VisitMemberBinding`

Comment: @RenéVogt `VisitMember` is a member access, e.g. when you are accessing a property of an object. `VisitMemberBinding` or more specific `VisitMemberInit` is when you use the initialization feature of C#. However, be careful because if you auto-initialize anonymous types, this looks like an initialization but in fact, the compiler renders it as a constructor call.

Comment: But aren't we talking about the expressions `e.Item1` and `e.Item2`? These _are_ property/member accesses. I tested it, `VisitMember` is called, `VisitMemberBinding` is not.

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar using VisitMemberAssignment:

```
namespace BoundPropertiesinQuery
{
    static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        class ProjectedVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            public IList<string> ProjectedPropertyNames { get; set; } = new List<string>();

            protected override MemberAssignment VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node)
            {
                ProjectedPropertyNames.Add(node.Member.Name);
                return base.VisitMemberAssignment(node);
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<string> ProjectedProperties<T>(this IQueryable<T> @this)
        {
            var pv = new ProjectedVisitor();
            pv.Visit(@this.Expression);
            return pv.ProjectedPropertyNames.Distinct();
        }
    }

    internal class MyObject
    {
        public int Property1 { get; set; }
        public int Property2 { get; set; }

        public int Property3 { get; set; }

        public int Property4 { get; set; }
    }

    internal class MyOtherObject
    {
        public int other1 { get; set; }

        public int other2 { get; set; }

        public int other3 { get; set; }

        public int other4 { get; set; }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var listOfItems = new List<MyOtherObject>()
            {
                new MyOtherObject
                {
                    other1 = 1,
                    other2 = 2,
                    other3 = 3,
                    other4 = 4
                },
                new MyOtherObject
                {
                    other1 = 5,
                    other2 = 6,
                    other3 = 7,
                    other4 = 8
                }
            };

           var result = listOfItems.AsQueryable().Select(m => new MyObject
               {
                   Property1 = m.other1,
                   Property2 = m.other2
               }).ProjectedProperties();

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```